# Civic duty - voting spree

Tags: discussion

This morning there was an expected surprise in my award overview. Thrice in a row either a question or answer of mine was downvoted. [image]

I receive downvotes too, but mostly as a response to a question/answer within a certain timespan. However this looked to fabricated. If someone was randomly or specifically targeting me and maybe others. Now the the rep-damage isn't something I worry about, but more about this voting behaviour. Research showed that these downvotes were done within two minutes.

A possible explanation is the civic-duty badge in combination with some grudge. The users downvoting gets voted counting towards this badge but doesn't want another user to get the rep?

However both cases are undesired, where a voting spree gives (undeserved) rep or rep-hits to users. And I wonder how to combat these, next to flagging the case to a moderator (as I did).

Comment: There are measures to check for serial voting. If it is not reversed by the system in 24 hours, I suggest raise a mod flag explaining the issue. I dont think Meta can do much here

Comment: Looks like you were never serial-downvoted before, welcome to the club.  Nothing to do with a badge, you just ticked somebody off.  No apparent reason that I see.  Somebody experienced, they knew when to stop.  It happens, best to move on with your life.

Comment: A moderator already got your flag, and already turned it over to Stack Exchange employees for investigation. That's all anyone can really do; no point in raising issues like this on Meta. All anyone can tell you is the standard stuff, contained in the duplicate.